# App crashes when using .xml vectors in Pre-Lollipop device | Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, vector, xamarin.android, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using .xml vector drawable in **xamarin.android** project.
When I run the app in **pre-lollipop** devices, app crashes because of not support vector drawable in pre-lollipop devices.

*I'm using *Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable* and *Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat* but it doesn't work.

What can I do?

-- I don't want to use .png images instead of .xml vectors!

Answer (score 1):

you can set image vector in the code for pre-lollipop for example:

ImageView image = new ImageView (this); 
 image.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.dt);